# ShareKit -facebook error - links must have 'href' and 'text' attributes

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoa, fbconnect, sharekit

I get the following error in a WebView:

Title:

> **Post to Wall**

Body:

> **action links must have string 'href' and 'text' attributes"**

Other buttons(navigation):

> **Okay**

Context:
ShareKit build 134529c, FBConnect plugged in.
I'm trying to post a url (http://www.google.com) to my wall.

The authentification is ok, the url is not nil.. I guess I should add those attributes somewhere, but I would prefer not to modify the FBConnect classes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I left the appURL blank in myDefaultSHKConfigurator. There should be somethig to indicate which fields are **mandatory**...

```
- (NSString*)appURL {
    return @""; //wrong
}
```

instead of

```
- (NSString*)appURL {
    return @"http://www.google.com"; //OK
}
```

I'll leave the problem here, maybe someone will run into it one day.